# Need Help Setting Up Fetch Predicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am unsure as to what to use for the `YourNameVariable`.  I think it needs to be an instance of Routine (or maybe the name property of Routine) but how do I create this?  I am using a UITableView.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

[request setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"routineExercises = %@", yourVariableNameHere]];

NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  managedObjectContext);

NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
}
[mutableFetchResults release];
[request release];
```

Here is my data model:
[image]

And also, should I be putting this in viewDidLoad or in the fetchResultsController's method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a fetch if you already have the `Routine` objects. You just ask the `Routine` object for the contents of its `routineExercises` relationship.

You use fetches when you don't have an object to start with. If you already have an object, then you walk it's relationships to find it's associated objects. Fetching objects that are already in a relationship defeats the purpose of having relationships in the first place.

Comment: Ok thanks.  So how would I edit my code above to reflect this? I have a table with a list of routines, each  routine should have its own specific list of exercises, right now,  whatever execise i add to a routine, shows up on all routines, instead  of just that specific routine.

 

For each entity of Routine, there should be a list of exercises.  Right now there seems to be the same list of exercises for all routines.

Comment: Not sure. The fetch as written should return only those `Exercise` objects that have a relationship to a particular `Routine` object. If you get the same `Exercise` objects for all fetches, then either (1) you are always providing the same `Routine` object to the predicate or (2) you have added all the `Exercise` objects to the same `Routine` object relationship.